# Could not calculate upgrade from Maverick Meerkat to Natty Narwhal

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates

I upgraded from Ubuntu `Lucid Lynx` to `Maverick Meerkat` with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo vi /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

and changed the last line to `Prompt=normal`

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

This upgrade was OK.

I decided to repeat the same steps and to upgrade `Maverick Meerkat` to `Natty Narwhal`.
It ended with this message:

> Building data structures... Done
>
> Calculating the changes
>
> Calculating the changes
>
> Could not calculate the upgrade
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade: Can
>   not mark 'xubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
>
> This can be caused by:
>   * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug against the
>   'update-manager' package and include the files in
>   /var/log/dist-upgrade/ in the bug report.
>
> Restoring original system state
>
> Aborting Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done Building data structures... Done
>   === Command detached from window (Mon Nov 21 09:37:21 2011) ===
>   === Command terminated with exit status 1 (Mon Nov 21 09:37:21 2011) ===

How can I correct it?

Comment: have you got any PPAs enabled in software sources or someother non-standard repository?

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/FAn1iGVJ) is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: also... the -d switch is to upgrade to the development version - you dont need to do this... what happens when you just run `sudo do-release-upgrade` ?

Comment: The upgrade is working without `-d`. You can write as an asnwer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of the error message you have reported is the following:

> - Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

Most often the error is due to PPAs still enabled - you should *ppa-purge* these repositories -

the format is

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:[ppa-name]
```

where the [ppa-name] is the name of the repository defined in your *software-sources* screen.

I also note you have used the syntax `do-release-upgrade -d`.  The `-d` flag denotes *upgrade to the latest available development release*.

A simple `sudo do-release-upgrade` should be sufficient to upgrade to the next stable release of Ubuntu.